# multiple times binding issue

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I spent a lot of time trying to solve that issue. How I can do that two bindings on the same element?
Would appreciate any suggestions

```
var app: any = new App();
    app.links.push({
        action: () => {
            $.ajax({   
                type: 'POST',
                url: url
            }).done(data => {                                  
                       require(['App/App'], App=> {
                           console.log("App Filse Loaded");
                           this.app = new App();
                           ko.applyBindings(this.app);// Error "You cannot apply 
                                                      // bindings multiple times 
                                                      // to the same element"
                           this.app.isLoaded(true);
                           this.app.isReady(true);
                       });
            })
        },
        label : 'Create Subscription',
    });           
    ko.applyBindings(app);
});
```

Comment: The whole point of binding is to bind once and then get updates. Why binding twice?

Comment: You can have multiple bindings, but you only applyBindings once.

Comment: what I need is to clean element's binding somehow

Comment: the simplest way is to just have two objects and then set one of them to undefined. I'm still a bit unclear why you are wanting to bind to the same element. Can't you just use two different elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sure that ko.cleanNode before second binding will do the trick.But it is very bad practice

Answer (score 1):

This allows you to change the model on the same element using a nested object:

html:

```
<div data-bind="with: model">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: changeModel">Change Model</button>
```

javascript:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var model = {
        name: 'John'
    };

    var viewModel = new ViewModel(model);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});

var ViewModel = function(model) {
    var self = this;

    var nestedViewModel = new NestedViewModel(model);
    self.model = ko.observable(nestedViewModel);

    self.changeModel = function(){
        var model = {
            name: 'Max'
        };

        var nestedViewModel = new NestedViewModel(model);
        self.model(nestedViewModel);
    };
};

var NestedViewModel = function(model) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = model.name;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bmc7D/